# I want to insert datarow filter value to dataset new row

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, datarow

I want to insert datarow filter value to datatable new row. am using a dataset with values. am using some expression to filter the dataset row using datarow.rowfilter. Now datarow.row filter having a row. Now i want to insert that row to datatable but i can't do this.. Please help me to do this..

My partial code is here..

```
   DV = DS.DefaultView;
   DT = DS.Copy();
   DT1 = DT.Clone();

                foreach (DataRow dr in DS.Rows)
                {

                    DT1.NewRow();             
                    forward1 = Convert.ToString(dr["fldforward1"]);
                    forward2 = Convert.ToString(dr["fldforward2"]);
                    forward3 = Convert.ToString(dr["fldforward3"]);
                    forward4 = Convert.ToString(dr["fldforward4"]);
                    forward5 = Convert.ToString(dr["fldforward5"]);
                    string status = Convert.ToString(dr["fldstatus"]);
                    string date1 = Convert.ToString(dr["fldrequestdate"]);

                    if (" " == forward1)
                    {
                        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "temp", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Error for reading data...');</script>", false);
                    }
                    else if ("" == forward2)
                    {

                        DV.RowFilter = "fldforward1='" + forward1 + "' and fldstatus='Pending' and  fldrequestdate='" + date1 + "'";
                       // DT1.Rows.Add(DV); //DV.RowFilter having a row . I want to insert to datatable DT1 row 

                    }


                }
```

Please help me to do this....

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure there will be only one row, then you can use

```
DT1.ImportRow(DS.Select("fldforward1='" + forward1 + "' and fldstatus='Pending' and  fldrequestdate='" + date1 + "'")[0]);
```

Comment: it give the  Error The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.DataTable.ImportRow(System.Data.DataRow)' has some invalid arguments